# Laravel custom policy method always returning 403

Tags: laravel

**Route**

```php
Route::get('/post/preview/{slug}', [PostController::class, 'viewPreview'])->name('post.single.preview');
```

**PostController**

```php
protected function resourceAbilityMap()
{
    return array_merge(parent::resourceAbilityMap(), [
        'viewPreview' => 'viewPreview'
    ]);
}

public function viewPreview($slug)
{
    $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

    $this->authorize('viewPreview', $post);

    return view('post.single', [
        'post' => $post,
        'morePosts' => $this->getMorePosts($post->id, 3),
    ]);
}
```

**PostPolicy**

```php
public function viewPreview(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return true;
}
```

Whether I put `true` or `false` in the policy method, it always returns a 403. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The part

```php
protected function resourceAbilityMap()
{
    return array_merge(parent::resourceAbilityMap(), [
        'viewPreview' => 'viewPreview'
    ]);
}
```

Was not needed. I found it on SO but it's not in the official Laravel docs.

The issue was that when testing I was not logged in, and Laravel will always return `false` for policy methods where the type-hinted model is required (in this case `User $user`). For testing, adding `?` made it work: `viewPreview(?User $user, ...)`